# Parameterized nightwatch tests

Tags: nightwatch.js

Has there been any progress in Nightwatch to allow for parameterized tests? I found an old thread pointing to a package called nightwatch-data-driven, but that doesn't seem to work on newer versions of Node.js.

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
   import DataDrivenTest from 'nightwatch-data-driven';
   ^^^^^^
```

I'm not sure if anything new has come about in the 4 years since or if there is a way of forking this repo to work in a newer Node version.

I'm basically trying to use this concept similar to what you can do in nUnit (example below) for example where you cut down on repetitive test declarations for cases that vary in inputs and expectations only.

```
[TestCase(12, 3, 4)]
[TestCase(12, 2, 6)]
[TestCase(12, 4, 3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(q, n / d);
}
```

Comment: hi @EdgeCase.  What do you mean exactly when you say parameterized tests?  Are you wanting to create functions and such that allow for different variables to be passed through?  like that?

Comment: In test frameworks like nUnit for example you can use the [TestCase(...)] decorator and supply inputs, parameters, for your test function like in my example above so you can just write one test function and more efficiently pass it test cases that only vary in input and expected outcomes.

Comment: to be honest that seems like a job better-suited for something like JUnit since it seems like you're wanting to test the actual code.  Unless you're trying to assert the result of that function with a UI element.